# Need MV command

Tags: unix, mv

I need to rename a file, but keep the extension (whatever it might be, without specifying it)

For example:

`file_20161118.csv.ovr` needs to be renamed to `"file.csv.ovr"`.

However in some instances it might be `file_20161118.csv.rpl`, in which case I need it to be `"file.csv.rpl"`.

Thanks

Comment: `mv` just renames one file, or moves one or more files to a different location. It has no file name mangling support. It would also help if you can specify if you need a solution for HPUX, AIX, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Mac OS X, Illumos, or any of the dozens of other UNIX variants and Unix-like OSes out there.

Answer (score 1):

`rename`does the trick.

For example, a file called `file_20161118.csv.ovr` becomes `file.csv.ovr` after this command:

```
rename 's/file_20161118/file/' file_20161118*
```

It uses Perl regular expressions, so you can do a lot of things with it. Check more examples [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```
perl -e'for(@ARGV){ $f=$_; s/_(\d{8})\./\./; rename$f,$_}' file1 file2 files*
```